# How to make new text highlighted as well?

Tags: faces, highlighting

Run in `*scratch*`:

```
(progn (fundamental-mode) (hi-lock-mode 1) (highlight-regexp "." 'hi-pink))
```

Result:

[image: Screenshot showing all current text highlighted]

If I add text it is not highlighted depending on where I add it:

[image: Screenshot with some text not highlighted]

*How can I make all newly added text be highlighted?*

Note that it is OK for me to use something other than `hi-lock-mode`, as long as I can quickly toggle highlighting / the face of all characters.

I am using: `GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30) of 2018-07-05`

Comment: I'm trying to understand the use case here. Do you just want to highlight all text or just text added within a certain time from now?

Comment: Depending on what you want: 1. `C-mouse-2` and pick a face will make inserted text use that face. 2. See the Emacs manual, node [Enriched Text](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Enriched-Text.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying it out in `fundamental-mode`.  As explained in the docstring of `hi-lock-mode`:

```
[...] In buffers where Font Lock mode is
disabled, patterns are applied using overlays; in this case, the
highlighting will not be updated as you type.
```

so in order for the matching to be done as you type, you need to be using font-lock in that buffer and that is disabled in `fundamental-mode`.

Comment: Thanks for finding that out! Indeed I forgot to mention that with the default `lisp-interaction-mode` in `*scratch*`, the issue does not appear. Only now I wonder why enabling `font-lock-mode` in `fundamental-mode` (which I want) still doesn't resolve the issue: `(progn (fundamental-mode) (font-lock-mode) (hi-lock-mode 1) (highlight-regexp "." 'hi-pink))`

Comment: @feklee: `font-lock-mode` doesn't really turn on in buffers that aren't setup explicitly for this (usually by the major mode) :-(

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, and the [solution is hacky](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FontLockForNewModes).

Answer (score 0):

Is `M-x highlight-changes-mode` what you are looking for? While it is enabled all newly added/changed text will be highlighted with the `highlight-changes` face.

Comment: Interesting mode, but in this case I want all characters be highlighted equally, and I want it to be possible to toggle highlighting on and off. It's actually for hiding passwords using the [Xecret font](https://fontlibrary.org/de/font/xecret). Changing the face for the entire buffer could be an option, and I decided against that, but I forgot why.